# Issue in migrating outlook task api (getAllTasks) to graph To-do task api

Tags: graph, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, outlook-restapi

We are in the process of Migrating from Outlook APIs to Graph Microsoft APIs.

We are unable to migrate task API as we don't find any graph API documentation relating to [getAllTasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/task-rest-operations#GetAllTasksV2).

Please help us to find this API.

Answer (score 1):

`getAllTasks` should be related to [List Todo task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/todotasklist-list-tasks?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) endpoint

```
GET /me/todo/lists/{todoTaskListId}/tasks
```

A `todoTask` represents a task, i.e. a piece of work or personal item that can be tracked and completed.

You need to know `todoTaskListId` of `todoTaskList`. A `todoTaskList` represents a logical container of `todoTask` resources.

Resources:

[Microsoft To Do API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todo-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)